# Deploy flat files from Bamboo to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, scp, bamboo

We deploy flat files to our web servers using bamboo SCP jobs.
I would like to move content from the web servers to S3, so need a Bamboo job to deploy static content to an S3 bucket.

I assumed it would be a 2 min job to make a build plan to deploy flat files to S3, but suspect I'm missing something obvious here, as I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create a "Script" in your build job.

Then export the AWS access keys in your build script:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAJA335522247FF
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=crNwiopyfDWD780wO32hv0cAkmzV65vyA3++No+
```

After that you can simply iterate over your files and copy them with the `aws` command to your desired bucket:

```
FILES="backups/*"
bucket="s3://my-backups/database/"

for f in $FILES
do
  file=`basename $f`
  echo "Processing $file"
  target=$bucket$file
  aws s3 cp $f $target
done
```

Alternatively you can copy also a folder:

```
aws s3 cp "my-files/" "s3://my-backups/" --recursive
```

Or, if you want to be even faster, you can only synchronize the changes:

```
aws s3 sync "my-files/" "s3://my-backups/"
```

Comment: For reference, here's the documentation for the AWS CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/